# How to retrieve DMARC record of DNS using java api?

Tags: java, dns, spf, dmarc

I want to retrieve the DMARC related record of DNS. This has been implemented by [this](https://dmarcian.com/dmarc-inspector/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
private void performDNSLookup(String address) {
    try {
        Resolver resolver = new SimpleResolver();
        Lookup lookup = new Lookup(address, Type.TXT);
        lookup.setResolver(resolver);
        Record[] record = lookup.run();
        for (int i = 0, len = record.length; i < len; i++)
            System.out.println(record[i].rdataToString() + "\n"
                    + record.length);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Use the above method where address is the DMARC URL for the given domain.

For eg: If one want to view DMARC record of google.com then the URL ,ie., address in given function is **_dmarc.google.com**. If **null** is returned then the domain doesn't have any DMARC record.

Comment: note: the above solution uses the dnsjava library (https://github.com/dnsjava/dnsjava).